# Пишу телеграмм бота на питоне. При нажатии кнопки нужно, чтобы отправилось видео

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При нажатии на кнопку я хочу, чтобы отправилось видео, но у меня кнопки inline типа. Я пытался сделать как-то через edit_message_text, но у меня не получалось. Можете дать пример решения?

Comment: добавить inline кнопке callback_data и  хендлерам отлавливать событие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка типа **inline** не предназначена для такого действия. Для этого есть обычные кнопки

**Если ответ помог, поставь галочку слева, новичёк.**